# Select_perm' lemma

Tags: coq, proof

I am currently having trouble proving this lemma:

```
Fixpoint select (x: nat) (l: list nat) : nat * list nat :=
  match l with
  | [] => (x, [])
  | h :: t =>
    if x <=? h
    then let (j, l') := select x t
         in (j, h :: l')
    else let (j, l') := select h t
         in (j, x :: l')
  end.

Lemma select_perm': ∀x l y r,
  (y, r) = select x l → Permutation (x :: l) (y :: r).
Proof.
```

What would be the best way to start?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would avoid the destructive `let` in the definition of `select`. This will allow you to easily use `pair_equal_spec` during the proof (and you will also need `surjective_pairing` at some point):

```
Require Import Nat List.
Import List Notations.

Fixpoint select (x: nat) (l: list nat) : nat * list nat :=
  match l with
  | [] => (x, [])
  | h :: t =>
    if x <=? h
    then let s := select x t
         in (fst s, h :: snd s)
    else let s := select h t
         in (fst s, x :: snd s)
  end.
```

Second, induction on `l` works perfectly fine, as long as you generalize `x`, `y`, and `r` first. This gives you an induction hypothesis that does not depend on these parameters.

```
Lemma select_perm' x l y r :
  (y, r) = select x l -> Permutation (x :: l) (y :: r).
Proof.
  generalize x y r.
  induction l.
```

Finally, you will need some facts about `Permutation` that should look intuitive and you can prove as an outside lemma.